# openmp: performance decreases with multiple threads on my desktop, but the opposite over my server

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I believe I read pretty much about StackOverflow threads regarding decreasing performance when increasing threads number with OpenMP. Mostly they were due to false sharing. My situation is quite different because my two machines are showing the opposite result.

I'm running [STREAM benchmark](https://github.com/jeffhammond/STREAM), and information about my machines is written below:

- Intel Xeon Gold-6148. 20 cores (40 threads), 2.4 GHz, 27.5MB LLC
- Intel Core i5-9400. 6 cores (6 threads), 2.9 GHz, 9MB LLC

Memory information is similar between the two machines so I will omit it.

I ran the benchmark quite a lot of times and checked the variance between runs is small enough. The result is quite interesting.

Gold-6148(a.k.a server) gets enhanced results when increasing threads number with the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` option. However, the result of i5-9400(a.k.a desktop) decreases with multiple threads number.

I set the `STREAM_ARRAY_SIZE` with 20m, and double-checked with various sizes, so it won't affect the result.
Also, I doubted maybe because of any difference over glibc/gomp library between the two, but no difference.

Any idea why this is happening? I just absentmindedly watching the chart below again and again...
[i5-9400 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w28wD.png)
[gold-6148 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Ed3.png)

Comment: Maybe i5-9700 is already fast enough to handle the workload with only a single thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Memory information is similar between the two machines so I will omit it.

You cannot simply omit the most important information when talking about the STREAM benchmark. [Xeon Gold 6148](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/120489/intel-xeon-gold-6148-processor-27-5m-cache-2-40-ghz.html) has **six DDR4-2666 memory channels** split over **two separate memory controllers** while [i5-9400](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134898/intel-core-i5-9400-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-10-ghz.html) (assuming i5-9700 is a typo since i7-9700 is an octo-core i7 and not a hexa-core i5 CPU) has only **two DDR4-2666 memory channels** on **a single memory controller**. Therefore, 6148 with memory modules installed on all six channels is capable of delivering 3x the memory bandwidth of i5-9400 with the same type of memory modules on both channels. It can also handle more simultaneous memory requests and therefore provides better memory utilisation with more than one thread. Thus, the actual memory configuration is quite important.

Interpreting the STREAM results requires deep understanding of the underlying CPU architecture. There is [a nice article](https://blogs.fau.de/hager/archives/8263) by Georg Hager on that topic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry that I didn't elaborate on the memory info.
It was actually similar, almost the same. Both using only one memory slot (I changed it for an apple-to-apple comparison), DDR4-2666 one DIMM. The only difference is that the module used on Xeon is 32GB while the Core is using an 8GB module. Since the modules are different (x4, x8 each), the actual DRAM timing must be slightly different. However, it won't cause the change.

Comment: Oh also thank you for pointing out the typo. I changed them all from i5-9700 to i5-9400 :)

Comment: In that case, I'm betting that the 32 GiB DIMM is probably a dual rank DIMM while the 8 GiB is a single rank one, which could explain why the Xeon starts with a bit lower bandwidth but then goes to a higher sustained bandwidth as a second thread is added.

Comment: Yes! Right! I need to prepare a dual-rank DIMM for i5-9400 and test again. Really appreciate your advice.

Comment: I believe this is another case of the so-called "memory wall". I've just tested by tuning one of the STREAM benchmark(triad) into a more complex one by adding a bunch of computational instructions to find that i5-9400 also shows a going-up graph. Probably it had been because the memory (1-rank) was too slow for the multi-threaded program. Thank you!

Comment: You really need to retry your experiments with Intel's compiler. It emits non-temporal (cache bypassing) access instructions for vectorised loops. At least what they now call the classic compiler does. Or rewrite the STREAM triad kernel with non-temporal store intrinsics.

Comment: Can I ask why you recommend that suddenly? AFAIK the microarchitectures of Skylake-SP and Coffeelake are almost the same except for the cache size and inclusion policy. Thus after I had read the article by Dr.Bandwidth regarding the streaming stroes, I was thinking about doing it. However, the thing is our conversation had nothing to do with the cache architecture. I am asking because it felt like you read my mind or were watching me from somewhere.

Comment: Hehe, not reading your mind. Just too many years benchmarking and optimising HPC applications for a living.